# Compling python3 program (include Pool) with Pyinstall error

Tags: python, pool

I want complie python3 program (include Pool)   with Pyinstall,It has some errors.
The name of my program is 'ls.py', When I compile the program with Pyintall ,It generate a program named 'ls.exe'.I run it,print Nothing.
My code is here:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print(x*x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(f,[1,2,3,4])
```

When I change the code:

```
#from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print(x*x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1,5):
        f(i)
```

And compile the program with Pyinstall,it run OK!
SO,I'm think the problem is caused by

```
'from multiprocessing import Pool'
```

So,Please help me with this problem,thanks

The version of Python 3.4,Pyinstall is   PyInstaller-3.2.1-py3.4.egg

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2**

Added `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` to the code and as a safety precaution moved code to `main()` function since we are calling  `if __name__ == "__main__":`

*Working Code:*

```
import multiprocessing
def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()
```

**EDIT1**

Upon further investigation, looks like your method works as well. Just change
`print(x*x)` to `return x*x`

```
def f(x):
    return x*x
```

**Original Post**
It seems you need to return result to mp thread , collect it and then print it.
A Pool object controls a pool of worker processes. Jobs can be submitted to the Pool, which then sends the jobs to the individual workers. Once job is done status is collected and returned to main process.

If you change `print(x*x)` to `return x*x` and also collect result in
`results = p.map(f,[1,2,3,4])`
Then print it using `print(results)`
The code works as intended.

**Working Code**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    results = p.map(f,[1,2,3,4])
    print(results)
```

**Output:**
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > [1, 4, 9, 16]

Comment: I test 2 melthold,It's both run ok in Python 2 or 3! The problem is:Compling it with Pyinstall;one way could run,other way with pool,it's wrong

Comment: Yes, OP had print statement inside a pool job. If its changed to return, code works good.

Comment: also， I add freeze_support() ，the exe program return nothing,help

Comment: see my edited response. Modified for `freeze_support()`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I  FOUND  THE MELTHOLD: ADD  pool.close()  pool.join()